# How to populate a RecyclerView with data from a Service on Button click

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have this setup in my fragment. The user makes selections from the spinners and when they click the go button a service is initiated that is meant to get data and populate a recycler view with the data.The recycler view is located right below the spinners.The code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/weekSpinner"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
        </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sessionSpinner"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weekSpinner"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weekSpinner"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
        </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/termSpinner"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sessionSpinner"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sessionSpinner"

            android:layout_margin="5dp">
        </Spinner>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go"
            android:id="@+id/resultsSearch"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sessionSpinner"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/toolBar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/caRecycler">

       </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting this error.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I understand that it has to do with the context being used but i have no idea how to solve it as this is the first time i'm using this sort of setup. Below is my fragment code.

```
public class caFragment extends Fragment
{
    ArrayList<String> weeks,terms,sessions;
    String selectedWeek,selectedTerm,selectedSession;
    String activeChild;
    Button go;
    private static final String selectedChildTracker = "selectedChild";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    static RecyclerView caDisplay = null;
    static caCardAdapter cardAdapter = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.results_ca,null);

        sharedpreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(selectedChildTracker, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        activeChild = sharedpreferences.getString("selectedChild",null);

        final Spinner week,term,session;
        setup();

        week = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.weekSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> weekAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,weeks);
        weekAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        week.setAdapter(weekAdapter);

        term = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.termSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> termAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,terms);
        termAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        term.setAdapter(termAdapter);

        session = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sessionSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sessionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sessions);
        sessionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        session.setAdapter(sessionAdapter);


        caDisplay = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.caRecycler);



        go = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.resultsSearch);

        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

              selectedWeek = week.getSelectedItem().toString();
              selectedTerm = term.getSelectedItem().toString();
              selectedSession = session.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Bundle extra = new Bundle();
                extra.putString("selectedWeek",selectedWeek);
                extra.putString("selectedTerm",selectedTerm);
                extra.putString("selectedSession",selectedSession);
                extra.putString("selectedChild",activeChild);

                try
                {
                    getActivity().startService(new Intent(getContext(), results.class).putExtras(extra));

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.print(ex);
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    public void setup()
    {
        weeks = new ArrayList<>();
        terms = new ArrayList<>();
        sessions = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            weeks.add("4");
            weeks.add("8");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error adding weeks",ex.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            terms.add("First Term");
            terms.add("Second Term");
            terms.add("Third Term");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error adding terms",ex.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            sessions.add("2015/2016");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error adding sessions",ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public void showResults()
    {
        cardAdapter = new caCardAdapter(getActivity(),cardResults.getResultSet());
        caDisplay.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
        caDisplay.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

}
```

and below is my service code

```
public class results extends Service
{
    int mStartMode;
    String tag_results_req = "tag_results_req";
    static ArrayList<cardResults> cardResult;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
       Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d("bundle param",params.toString());

        String week = params.getString("selectedWeek");
        String term = params.getString("selectedTerm");
        String session = params.getString("selectedSession");
        String child = params.getString("selectedChild");

        makeRequest(week,term,session,child);
        return mStartMode;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void makeRequest(String week,String term,String session,String child)
    {

        String dataSet = week.trim()+","+term+","+session.trim()+","+child.trim();
        byte[] data = new byte[0];
        try
        {
            data = dataSet.getBytes("UTF-8");

        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String query = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("Query param",query);

        //the url we are posting the request to
        String url = " http://mobile.map.education/api/result/ca/"+query;

        // prepare the Request
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                    {
                        // display response
                        Log.d("results",response.toString());
                        cardResults(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        Log.e("Error.Response", error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry there was an error getting results data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
        queuer.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, tag_results_req);
    }

    public void cardResults(JSONObject result)
    {
        cardResult = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray res = null;

        try
        {
            res = (JSONArray) result.get("result_details");
            Log.d("results",res.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("error getting results",ex.toString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject subject = res.getJSONObject(i);

                cardResults cardModel = new cardResults();

                cardModel.setAverage("50");
                cardModel.setScore(subject.getString("total"));
                cardModel.setSubject(subject.getString("subject"));
                cardModel.setAssignment(subject.getString("ASSIGNMENT"));
                cardModel.setTest(subject.getString("CLASS TEST"));
                cardModel.setWork(subject.getString("CLASS WORK"));
                cardModel.setTeacher(subject.getString("teacher"));

                cardResult.add(cardModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("card list",ex.toString());
            }
        }

        try {
            cardResults.setResultSet(cardResult);
            caFragment m = new caFragment();
            m.showResults();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("show result",ex.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think `getContext()` is null when you do `getActivity().startService(new Intent(getContext(),...`. Since an Activity is a Context, try to replace `getContext()` with `getActivity()`

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks but that didn't have any effect, i still get the same error

Comment: Do you really need the service? You can call volley directly from the click event. I would start debugging there. Also, can you provide the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem with your adapter which you are setting outside the `onCreate` of Fragment

```
cardAdapter = new caCardAdapter(getActivity());
caDisplay.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
caDisplay.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

move above lines inside the `onCreate` and just create one **data Setter** method in your Adapter class and then call this method to set data.

```
public void showResults()
{
    //create setter method inside your adapter and notify 
    cardAdapter.setData(cardResults.getResultSet());
    cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

before set Data just check that your data is not null!